# Reshape the bike share recorded data into bike share counts

Tags: r, reshape2

Everyone
I am struggling to reshape the bike share recorded data.
data link :
https://www.kaggle.com/code/samratp/bike-share-analysis/data?select=NYC-2016-Summary.csv

The original data form is recorded for each bike.

[image]

However I prefer to know the share counts for every in 2016.
that is a data frame `cinsist` of two variable, date and counts.

Thanks and appreciate for any suggestion

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example> with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Share count for every day of month? The data has no date, only day of the week and month.